# jquery file upload get fle name while attaching

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><br/>
<input id="fUpload" multiple type="file"/>
<ul id="ulList"></ul>
<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show"/><br/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnShow").on('click', function () {
    $("#ulList").empty();
    var fp = $("#fUpload");
    var lg = fp[0]
    .files.length; // get length
    var items = fp[0].files;
    var fragment = "";
    if (lg > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
            var fileName = items[i].name; // get file name
            var fileSize = items[i].size; // get file size 
            var fileType = items[i].type; // get file type
          // append li to UL tag to display File info
         fragment += "<li>" + fileName + " " + fileSize + " bytes. Type :" + fileType + "</li>";
        }
       $("#ulList").append(fragment);
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or please check this URL

http://codepedia.info/editor-example/get-file-details-in-jquery-name-size-type-example/

This is working fine for file upload in jquery but I want to get file name while choosing a file but I not able to get file name while click choose file button.

Any solution???

Answer (score 1):

You can listen the `change` event of the input file like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#fUpload").on("change", function(e) {
    $("#ulList").empty();
    var fp = $("#fUpload");
    var lg = fp[0]
      .files.length; // get length
    var items = fp[0].files;
    var fragment = "";
    if (lg > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
        var fileName = items[i].name; // get file name
        var fileSize = items[i].size; // get file size 
        var fileType = items[i].type; // get file type
        // append li to UL tag to display File info
        fragment += "<li>" + fileName + " " + fileSize + " bytes. Type :" + fileType + "</li>";
      }
      $("#ulList").append(fragment);
    }
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/tmv8rj42/